# How do I solve this trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

> Solve the equation $$\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}-\frac{x}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{10}+\frac{3x}{2}\right).$$

I tried  applying some Ratio properties, but they just made the equation nasty. Some hints please. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

**Method** $\#1:$

Let $\dfrac{3\pi}{10}-\dfrac x2=y\iff\dfrac x2=\dfrac{3\pi}{10}-y$

$\implies\dfrac\pi{10}+\dfrac{3x}2=\dfrac\pi{10}+3\left(\dfrac{3\pi}{10}-y\right)=\pi-3y$

So, we have $\sin y=\dfrac12\sin(\pi-3y)\iff2\sin y=\sin3y$

Now use $\sin3y=3\sin y-4\sin^3y$ and $\cos2B=1-2\sin^2B$

**Method** $\#2:$

As $\sin(180^\circ-B)=\sin B,$

$$\sin(18^\circ+3x/2)=\sin\left[180^\circ-(18^\circ+3x/2)\right]=\sin3(54^\circ-x/2)$$

Write $\sin(54^\circ-x/2)=u$ and use $\sin3y=3\sin y-4\sin^3y$

**Method** $\#3:$

$$\sin(54^\circ-x/2)=\sin[90^\circ-(36^\circ+x/2)]=\cos(36^\circ+x/2)$$

As $\cos(90^\circ+A)=-\sin A,$

$$\sin(18^\circ+3x/2)=-\cos(90^\circ+18^\circ+3x/2)=-\cos3(36^\circ+x/2)$$

Write $\cos(36^\circ+x/2)=u$ and use $\cos3y=4\cos^3y-3\cos y$